# is there an API-level error handler in the ArcGIS Server JS API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm seeing an error message in FireBug:

```
Error: Internal kml parser error.http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/js.../?v=3.2compact
Line 34
```

I'm not worried about fixing this error for the moment - I'd like to know how can I **trap** the error, so I can report it to the user elegantly? Eg, if they're not using Firebug I'd still like them to know that there's a problem.

The map has an [onLayersAddResult](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/map.htm#onLayersAddResult) event, which contains an Error handler. Is there a similar map-level error handling event which would trap the above KML parser error (and any other errors which might be generated by the API)?

It seems like the `map` object needs a generic `onError()` event, but I can't see anything suitable.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like that error is coming from Firefox itself. It's getting passed bad KML (or so it thinks) so I don't think you're going to be able to trap that.

Comment: @Mintx maybe this is a question for a web/browser group rather than GIS specifically? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to address the GIS question specifically, from what I've seen, trapping errors usually consists of extensive try/catches or fetching the JSON response and parsing it before sending it to your functions and catching errors that way. ESRI is slowing coming around to adding error events in their API.